# Unable to initialize constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, constexpr

When compiling this code with clang (version 3.0-6ubuntu3):

```
constexpr int foo(const int n) {
    return n + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    constexpr int x = 5 * 4 + 12 + 8;
    constexpr int y = foo(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Using this command:

```
clang -std=c++11 -c constexprExample.cpp
```

I get following error:

> error: constexpr variable 'y' must be initialized by a constant expression

Is it something wrong with code or the compiler?

Comment: Try define y as const instead of constant expression....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in clang 3.0 that's fixed in 3.1.